# How can I undo all changes to a block of text in vim?

Tags: vim, undo

Is it possible to select some text with visual line and undo all changes made to it from the beginning ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually do that by undoing everything yanking the block then redoing everything to the last modification and then replacing the block with the yanked text.

Comment: +1 May be ok when block fits on the screen and there are not many things to undo/redo. Troublesome otherwise.

Comment: why does it need to fit in the screen? but yes, the undolevel matters.

Comment: or you can save the file to a different name and then comparing the two versions with vimdiff - this solves the undolevel problem

Comment: @KARASZI It doesn't "need" to. But is easier for me to manipulate with.

Comment: I would like to note that multi-level undo requires 'set nocompatible', which is not default.