# VIM:: Undo changes on or around the specified text

Tags: vim, undo-redo

In VIM is it possible to undo changes on or around a specific block of text? Lets say I make change A right above `"if yes"`, then do changes B, C, D and E in other places on the file. Is it possible to tell vim "undo changes that were done with in +/- 10 lines from `if yes`?

I've come across [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236099/how-can-i-undo-all-changes-to-a-block-of-text-in-vim) that suggest this isn't possible, or at least in vanilla vim. Does any know of any plugins that would allow for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304 you can easily move around the undo tree.

1. So just go back to the original section (around  `if yes`), mark it with `ma`,
2. Go back to it's previous state on the tree (even if it undoes other changes).
3. Copy (yank) the region you want to keep to a register (e.g. select visual lines - `V5j"by`).
4. Get back to the actual state (last item on the Gundo tree).
5. Jump back to the section you want to change (`'a`)
6. Deleted the section you want to revert, and replace it with the contents of `b` register.

Comment: I've actually wanted to use Guno for some time, but the server I'm running off of is using VIM 7.1 and that requires 7.3 :L

Comment: Actually I had compiled Vim to my home dir on a big server which won't get upgraded any time soon from Vim 6.0 ;-)

Comment: I tried compiling from src without root access and configure complains (error) about missing "ncurses" :L I can't install it without root :O

Answer (score 11):

@Zsolt's answer is probably very interesting, I'd have to get acquainted with that.

What I usually do is, doing something like

<kbd>100g-</kbd> (go back to history snapshot that contained the thing you want to restore)

yank your 'rescue' text using some method, e.g.

```
:12,17yank
```

<kbd>999g+</kbd> (return to the tip of history)

use regular edit actions to restore the yanked lines into place.

Comment: (Actually it's "Zsolt" :-) but never mind.) And thank you for teaching me about `g-` and `g+`.